# Isn't the hector_quadrotor stack catkinized?

Tags: catkin, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although the stack (and all the packages) seems to be catkinized I am unable to install the packages. Whenever I run the catkin_make command (after arranging the folder structure for catkin) the devel and install folder are not created.

the terminal output when I run catkin_make is

Base path: /home/saroj/ros/ros_ws

Source space: /home/saroj/ros/ros_ws/src

Build space: /home/saroj/ros/ros_ws/build

Devel space: /home/saroj/ros/ros_ws/devel

Install space: /home/saroj/ros/ros_ws/install

##### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/saroj/ros/ros_ws/build"

##### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/saroj/ros/ros_ws/build"

saroj@saroj:~/ros/ros_ws$

(I have just started using ROS (even ubuntu) and I apologize if the question sounds stupid)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77731/isn%27t-the-hector_quadrotor-stack-catkinized?/) by [espee](https://answers.ros.org/users/6531/espee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2013-09-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-09-10**:
What repository / branch have you checked out? Do the directories contain package.xml or manifest.xml files?

**Comment by [espee](https://answers.ros.org/users/6531/espee/) on 2013-09-10**:
I am using tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor repository and hydro_devel branch. The directories do have manifest.xml...

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-09-10**:
There is your answer: it is not catkinized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a catkinized version of the hector_quadrotor stack now in the catkin branch (forked from hydro-devel):

https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor/tree/catkin

It is still under development and some packages have been reorganized for hydro. There are plans to do some more tests, update the rviz configs etc. and then release hector_quadrotor in hydro, but there was no time for that until now.

We would be glad if you and others can test the catkin branch and report bugs or submit pull requests via the [GitHub bugtracker](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor/issues).

---

Originally posted by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) with karma: 1266 on 2013-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [espee](https://answers.ros.org/users/6531/espee/) on 2013-09-11**:
Thank you so much. I will definitely try and report any problems I face.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the directories contain manifest.xml files (instead of package.xml files) than the packages are not catkinized and still use the "old" rosbuild. Please use rosmake to build them.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-09-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [espee](https://answers.ros.org/users/6531/espee/) on 2013-09-10**:
Thanks for the answer.